# I get stuck in my recursion

Tags: algorithm, function, recursion, racket

I have a problem with my Racket programm.
I want to add this function to my programm but I get stuck in my recursion:

Here the function:

```
ggt: N x N -> N
(m,n) -> 

ggT(m-n,n) if m > n

ggT(m,n-m) if n > m

m if m=n



(define (ggT m n)
  (cond
    [(> m n)(ggT (- m n)] ;; If m > n the programm should go recursiv back and change
                          ;; the value of m to m-n. But I know that this wont work this way
    [(< m n)(ggT (- n m)] ;; Same Problem here
    [else m]))
```

How do I start a real recursion?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
(define (ggT m n)
  (cond [(> m n) (ggT (- m n) n)]
        [(< m n) (ggT m (- n m))]
        [else m]))
```

You just have to pass the parameters in the correct order when calling the `ggT` function, remember that `ggT` receives *two* parameters, but you were passing only one.

Answer (score 2):

Your function `ggT` takes two parameters, but you are only passing 1 in. I think you want something like this:

```
(define (ggT m n)
  (cond
    [(> m n)(ggT (- m n) n)]                          
    [(< m n)(ggT m (- n m))]
    [else m]))
```

Comment: This solution is incorrect, the second recursive call doesn't match the one in OP's specification.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez - That's because when I posted my answer the question was different. It's now been edited any I've updated accordingly.